# pthread_create with local variable as parameter

Tags: c++, pthreads, posix, local-variables

May it cause errors when I use pthread_create in the following way?

```
void myFunction(){
  thread_t myThread;
  pthread_create(&myThread,0,myRoutine,0);
}
```

I am not sure if the usage of the local variable `myThread` can cause errors because it ceases to exist when `myFunction()` exits.

Could the memory of `myThread` still be used in the kernel when the function exits?

I will not need the thread id stored in `myThread` so I don't want to allocate memory and free it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also pass PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED as part of thread attribute when you create it. This way, you dont have to worry about joining the thread later on. Something like this:

```
 pthread_t;
 int status;
 pthread_attr_t attr;

 status = pthread_attr_init(&attr);
 if (status != 0) {
     fprintf(stderr, "pthread_attr_init() failed [status: %d]\n", status);
     return 0;
 }

 status = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
 if (status != 0) {
     fprintf(stderr, "pthread_attr_setdetachstate() failed [status: %d]\n", status);
     return 0;
 }

 status = pthread_create(&t, &attr, myRoutine, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't let a thread "just finish", as that can definitely cause problems. If you expect the thread to just finish on it's won, you should AT LEAST use `pthread_detach`, at which point the thread is completely "freestanding", and should be OK to just leave it be.

Answer (score 2):

> May it cause errors when I use `pthread_create` in the following way?

Yes: you now have no way to join the thread when it finishes. This is a resource leak, analogous to losing the only pointer to allocated memory.

If you really don't want to shut it down in a controlled way, then you could call `pthread_detach` to make it responsible for tidying up its own resources; then you can safely abandon the thread handle.

> Could the memory of `myThread` still be used in the kernel when the function exits?

No. `pthread_t` is just a handle used to access a thread's resources. It doesn't manage those resources, and it doesn't need to exist unless you need to access them.